# How to make a custom template in flutter like skeleton template in flutter 2.5

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

How to make a custom template in flutter like skeleton template in flutter 2.5. In flutter 2.5 we can create a skeleton template by 'flutter create -t template skeleton appname'. Instead of this skeleton can we replace it with our own custom template in flutter?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there's no easy way to create a template similar to skeleton, package, and plugin. There's an open [issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89833) for this feature. However, if you really need to create one. You can explore how `skeleton` was added as a template on this [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/83530).